# browser.visit object has no attribute

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I am getting an Attribute error on line 8:`browser.visit("https://www.facebook.com")`.

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'visit'"

This is my code:

```
browser = Browser('firefox')

browser.visit('https://www.facebook.com')

browser.find_by_id('email').fill("")

browser.find_by_id('pass').fill("")

browser.find_by_id('loginbutton').first.click()

browser.visit('')

while x != 0:

    browser.find_by_css('textarea').fill('')
    browser.find_by_id('u_0_1c').click()
```

It pulled up with a bunch of errors at first but I fixed those, I don't understand this error? If someone could maybe explain why or what is happening it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have  import the `Browser` package from `splinter` like this

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox)
browser.visit('https://www.facebook.com')
```